# Changing the password of the logged in user via the Azure AD B2C Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Graph API to change the user of the currently logged in user on a B2C tenant.

The request is being posted to:

```
https://graph.windows.net/me/changePassword?api-version=1.6
```

The JSON being provided is in the following format:

```
{"currentPassword":"[currentpassword]","newPassword":"[newpassword]"}
```

Unfortunately I keep on getting the following error and I don't know why (or rather I don't know why it would have problems using the 'me' alias). I have also tried including the tenant name with regards to where I'm posting the request but this makes no difference.

> Resource not found for the segment 'me'.

I have managed to change the password by resetting it. The issue with that however is that the password can be changed without providing the current password. Ideally I would like to get the user to have to enter this as part of the process of updating the password. It turns out that the missing 'me' issue is probably down to missing permissions.

I've tried adding the 'Access directory as the signed in user' permission as a delegated permission to the app. I get to this page:

[image]

Note that I also has to set the sign-in url to http://localhost/testapp/ and the app ID URI set to https://patrickscorp.onmicrosoft.com/testapp as the classic portal refuses to save changes if these two settings are not set.

Under 'permissions to other applications' I clicked on 'Add application' and then selected 'Windows Azure Active Directory'. I then made sure that the 'Access directory as signed in user' was selected.

[image]

However saving just results in the following error appearing:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Clicking 'details' doesn't help - it just says if the problems persist to contact
support

If I have to go down the reset route then is there a way of taking a password provided by the user and validating it?

Comment: You did not explain how you acquired the token. Did you acquire it from Azure AD B2C authentication endpoint? If so, then, unfortunately, as of today, you cannot call Azure AD B2C Graph API using that token. That means you cannot use the /me endpoint either.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Do you have any idea if and when this will be possible? I note that judging from the suggested improvements that this is an omission that has been hanging around for quite some time now despite repeated requests. Currently the only option I have is to allow the user to reset their password without providing the current one. This means anybody with physical access to the PC could change it without anything to stop them even if they are not the user in question. Programmatically logging in (to validate password) is also not an option it seems in context of a web app.

Comment: In order for the user to reset his/her password, they need to have access to the user's email as a verification email is sent as the password reset flow. So it's not just a matter of having access to the PC where the user is already signed-in to the Azure AD B2C powered app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think there's a timeline at this point of when it might be possible. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Calls to the [Azure AD Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog) requires the tenantName in the path, like so:

```
https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/me/changePassword?api-version=1.6
```

This is in contrast with the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) which doesn't require it as it infers it from the user token and is called like so:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/changePassword
```

However it is important to note that at this time the Azure AD Graph is recommended for Azure AD B2C.

**EDIT**:
As per the [Azure AD Graph Reference for Change Password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/functions-and-actions#changePassword):

> Call the changePassword action for the signed-in user to change their own password.
>
> **Note:** This action can only be called on the signed-in user.

If you want to change some other user's password, you'll need to use the [Reset Password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword):

```
https://graph.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/users/{user_id}?api-version=1.6
```

Comment: That's what I had started out doing but it wasn't working. Some of the examples I've seen seemed to exclude the tenant name which is why I tried that too. In any case it doesn't matter if the tenant name is included or not: I still get the error either way.

Comment: Are you using the client credentials flow? That would cause that error. There is no "me" when you are using client credentials (and thus authenticating as an app not a user). In that case you should explicitly specify the user via /objectId/changePassword.

Comment: I tried using the /objectId/changePassword route but it comes back with 403 forbidden (the URL in it's entirety is in the format of https://graph.windows.net/<mytenant>/users/<objectId>/changePassword?api-version=1.6). Do I need to modify permissions somewhere?

Comment: @PatrickS, updated the answer with more info that hopefully addresses your question.

Comment: It still doesn't work, however I think I know what the problem may be: the 'Access directory as the signed in user' delegated permission hasn't been set (d'oh) but whilst the option to enable it is shown in the classic Azure portal it won't let me set it (it comes back with a useless generic error message that tells me nothing). The option to enable it doesn't seem to be shown at all in the new portal. Any idea what could be causing the error? (thanks for all the help by the way)

Comment: Create a separate post with screenshots of your issue, that way it'll be easier to help you out.

Comment: I've updated the original post to include screenshots.

Comment: How did you create this test app? Can you try giving the app the permission from the [new Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com). For Graph operations, you need to use a v1 Azure AD app (created via the App Registrations blade in the new Azure portal), not a B2C app (created via the B2C blades in the new Azure portal).